# How to pass boolean value from Handlebars to Node?

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to pass a 0 or 1 to my mySql database for lbs or kgs as a boolean value.  I have created a select option for my handlebars as below to choose either the 0 or 1 option when I post the exercise -

```
<h1>MySQL Results:</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Exercise Name</th>
        <th>Reps</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Lbs</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each exercise}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{reps}}</td>
            <td>{{weight}}</td>
            <td>{{date}}</td>
            <td>{{lbs}}</td>
            <td><button onclick="deleteExercise({{id}})">Delete</button></td>
            <td><a href="/exercise/{{id}}">Update</a></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
    <form id="addexercise" action="/exercise" method="post">
    Exercise Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Reps: <input type="number" name="reps"><br>
    Weight: <input type="number" name="weight"><br>
    Date: <input type="date" name="date"><br>
    Lbs: <select name="lbs-select" id="lbs-select" val="{{lbs-select}}">
                <option value="0">Lbs</option>
                <option value="1">Kgs</option>
        </select><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</table>
```

Now how do I pass this to my post route?

```
        router.post('/', function(req, res){
                var mysql = req.app.get('mysql');
                var sql = "INSERT INTO workouts (name, reps, weight, date, lbs) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
                var inserts = [req.body.name, req.body.reps, req.body.weight, req.body.date, req.body.lbs //should this be something else? It should correspond to 0 or 1];
                sql = mysql.pool.query(sql, inserts, function(error, results, fields){
                        if(error){
                                res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
                                res.end();
                        } else{
                                res.redirect( '/exercise');
                        }
                });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Lbs: <select name="lbs-select" id="lbs-select" val="{{lbs-select}}">
            <option value="0">Lbs</option>
            <option value="1">Kgs</option>
    </select><br>
```

since name is "lbs-select" your code in node should also correspond to the same name.

```
 router.post('/', function(req, res){
            var mysql = req.app.get('mysql');
            var sql = "INSERT INTO workouts (name, reps, weight, date, lbs) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            var inserts = [req.body.name, req.body.reps, req.body.weight, req.body.date, req.body.lbs-select //changed from lbs to lbs-select];
            sql = mysql.pool.query(sql, inserts, function(error, results, fields){
                    if(error){
                            res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
                            res.end();
                    } else{
                            res.redirect( '/exercise');
                    }
            });
```